# AccessTokenRefreshError on Google API Class design

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api-python-client

I am trying to make a Base class for the basic boiler plate initialization of my Google API calls. From reading tutorials online, I take it that the http transport object should be re-used instead of re-initialized on every call.

Some basic info:

**Platform**: Google's AppEngine - Python 2.7 with threading enabled

**Error**:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/kay/app.py", line 371, in get_response response = view_func(request, **values)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/kay/handlers/__init__.py", line 34, in __call__ return func(**kwargs)

File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1047, in add_context_wrapper return synctasklet(func)(*args,
**kwds)

File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1029, in synctasklet_wrapper return taskletfunc(*args,
**kwds).get_result()

File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result self.check_success()

File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 371, in _help_tasklet_along value = gen.send(val)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/<app-name-removed>/backoffice/__init__.py", line 64, in post bigquery = BigQueryClient()

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/<app-name-removed>/api/google/base.py", line 68, in __init__ self.service = build(self.serviceName, self.version, http=credentials.authorize(http))

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/apiclient/discovery.py", line 193, in build resp, content = http.request(requested_url)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/oauth2client/client.py", line 405, in new_request self._refresh(request_orig)

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~<app-name-removed>/gapitest.363541807102146863/oauth2client/appengine.py", line 162, in _refresh raise AccessTokenRefreshError(str(e))

AccessTokenRefreshError
```

Base class implementation:

```
import os, httplib2, abc, logging
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from oauth2client.client import Storage, Credentials
from google.appengine.api import memcache

http = None

class FileStorage(Storage):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._filepath = filepath

    def locked_get(self):
        with open(self._filepath, 'r') as f:
            json = f.read()
        credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(json)
        return credentials

class BaseGoogleAPIClient(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    """The following is not ideal, would prefer abstract class properties"""

    @classmethod
    def get_scope(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError("Must define the authorization scope required for this class (multiple scopes should be seperated by a space)")

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def serviceName(self):
        """Define the Service this class will interface with"""
        return

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def version(self):
        """Define the Version of the API we will interface with"""
        return


    def __init__(self):
        global http

        if not http:
            if not os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development'):
                scopes = []

                for sc in BaseGoogleAPIClient.__subclasses__():
                    for scope in sc.get_scope().split(' '):
                        if not scope in scopes:
                            scopes.append(scope)

                logging.debug("Scopes {scopes}".format(scopes=scopes))

                credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=scopes)
            else:
                """USED FOR LOCAL TESTING"""
                filepath = #PATH REMOVED
                storage = FileStorage(filepath)
                credentials = storage.get()
            http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))

        self.service = build(self.serviceName, self.version, http=http)
```

I must be misunderstanding something or my design is flawed. It worked perfectly fine when I dedicated a separate class for each API I wanted to interface with (BigQuery & Storage). I'm just trying to share the constructor between classes.

This method works perfectly fine locally, although that's using a different credentials mechanism.

Example of an implementation of this class:

```
class BigQueryClient(BaseGoogleAPIClient):

    @classmethod
    def get_scope(cls):
        return 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'

    @property
    def serviceName(self):
        return 'bigquery'

    @property
    def version(self):
        return 'v2'

    #METHODS REMOVED
```

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly? Is my design flawed and is there a better way to implement what I want to do? I think I don't have to build the service interface every single time, but if I didn't would it be threadsafe? Is this method even threadsafe?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try getting this to work without all this dressing first. A refresh error probably just means you don't have a valid refresh token.

Comment: It was working before I tried to create a `Base` class